# R - How to split text and punctuation with a exception?

Tags: r, regex, text, split, gsub

Analysing Facebook comments in R for Sentimental Analysis. Emojis are coding in text between <> symbols.

Example:

```
"Jesus te ama!!! <U+2764>  Ou não...?<U+1F628> (fé em stand by)"
```

`<U+2764>` and `<U+1F628>` are emojis (heavy black heart and fearful face, 
respectively).

So, I need split words/numbers and punctuations/symbols, except in emoji codes.
I did, using gsub function, this:

```
a1  <- "([[:alpha:]])([[:punct:]])"
a2 <- "([[:punct:]])([[:alpha:]])"
b <- "\\1 \\2"
gsub(a1, b, gsub(a2, b, "Jesus te ama!!! <U+2764>  Ou não...?<U+1F628> (fé em stand by)"))
```

...but, the results, logically, also affects emojis code:

```
[1] "Jesus te ama !!! < U +2764>  Ou não ...?< U +1F628> ( fé em stand by )"
```

The objective is create a exception for the text between <>, split it externally and don't split internally - i.e.:

```
[1] "Jesus te ama !!! <U+2764>  Ou não ...? <U+1F628> ( fé em stand by )"
```

> Note that:
>
> > 1. sometimes the space between the sentence/word/punct and a emoji code is non-existent (needs to be created)
> > 2. It is required that a punct sequence stays join (e.g. "!!!", "...?")

How can I do it?

Comment: I had that same problem some time ago, albeit I discarded most emojis, but left only half a dozen or so that were particularly common and relevant for my particular sentiment analysis. 
So I replaced the relevant unicodes for a consistent string (i.e. gsub("U+1F642|U+263A","emoji_happy_faces", df$comment) and only afterwards did i remove punctuation with the tm package. Hope it helps.
(All emoji unicdoes can be found here: http://unicode.org/emoji/charts/full-emoji-list.html)

Answer (score 1):

You may use the following regex solution:

```
a1  <- "(?<=<)U\\+\\w+>(*SKIP)(*F)|(?<=\\S)(?=<U\\+\\w+>)|(?<=[[:alpha:]])(?=[[:punct:]])|(?<=[[:punct:]])(?=[[:alpha:]])"
gsub(a1, " ", "Jesus te ama!!! <U+2764>  Ou não...?<U+1F628> (fé em stand by)", perl=TRUE)
# => [1] "Jesus te ama !!! <U+2764>  Ou não ...? <U+1F628> ( fé em stand by )"
```

See the [online R demo](http://ideone.com/gw7ptY)

This PCRE regex (see `perl=TRUE` argument in the call to `gsub`) matches:

- `(?<=<)U\\+\\w+>(*SKIP)(*F)` - a `U+` and 1+ word chars with `>` after if preceded with `<`  - and the match value is discarded with the PCRE verbs `(*SKIP)(*F)` and the next match is looked for from the end of this match
- `|` - or
- `(?<=\\S)(?=<U\\+\\w+>)` -  a non-whitespace char must be present immediately to the left of the current location, and a `<U+`, 1+ word chars and `>` must be present immediately to the right of the current location
- `|` - or
- `(?<=[[:alpha:]])(?=[[:punct:]])` - a letter must be present immediately to the left of the current location, and a punctuation must be present immediately to the right of the current location
- `|` - or
- `(?<=[[:punct:]])(?=[[:alpha:]])` - a punctuation must be present immediately to the left of the current location, and a letter must be present immediately to the right of the current location

Comment: The `(?<=<)U\\+\\w+>(*SKIP)(*F)|` part allows skipping the replacement inside `<U+...>`, and `(?<=\\S)(?=<U\\+\\w+>)` part enables inserting spaces in between the sentence/word/punct and a emoji code.

Answer (score 1):

```
> str <- "Jesus te ama!!! <U+2764>  Ou não...?<U+1F628> (fé em stand by)"
> strsplit(str,"[[:space:]]|(?=[.!?])",perl=TRUE)
[[1]]
 [1] "Jesus"     "te"        "ama"       "!"         "!"         "!"        
 [7] ""          "<U+2764>"  ""          "Ou"        "não"       "."        
[13] "."         "."         "?"         "<U+1F628>" "(fé"       "em"       
[19] "stand"     "by)"
```