# How to split a string between emojies in R

Tags: r, regex, split, emoji

I am looking for a regular expression to split strings between words, punctuation and emojis.
I figured the easiest way would be to create additional white space and split by this as it is done in another answer: [R - How to split text and punctuation with a exception?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45535726/r-how-to-split-text-and-punctuation-with-a-exception)

Unfortunately, the regex does not work between two emojies, eg.

```
"paÍ<U+4146><U+534C><U+0A45><U+3B54>"
```

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Comment: Using a positive look-behind looking for `>` will get you going in the right direction: `strsplit("paÍ<U+4146><U+534C><U+0A45><U+3B54>", "(?<=>)", perl = TRUE)`

Comment: Without splitting it into two steps, you could specify a limited list of punctuation that doesn't overlap with the `<U+534C>` format to split other parts of the string, a pattern like this `"(?<=>)|\\s|[,.';]"` might be heading in the right direction. That will split by white space and any of these `,.';` characters. You can add more in the brackets except for ones that would split up your emoji bits.

Comment: Thanks! Unfortunately, this still does not solve the issue of how to split between alphabetic characters and emojis. Any recommendations for that?